# Typescript Add calculated value to class

Tags: angular, typescript

In an Angular project with Typescript I have class Person with Date of Birth (dob) property, but in the view I would like to be able to display a calculated value - age.

**person.model.ts**

```
import { differenceInYears, parse } from "date-fns"
export class Person {
  constructor(
    public name: string,
    public dob: Date,
  ) { }
}

//fake data
export let persons:Person[]=[];
  persons = [
    new Person("John", new Date('1976-01-26T00:00:00')),
    new Person("Julia", new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')),
    new Person("John", new Date('1967-07-05T00:00:01')),
    new Person("Ryan", new Date('2010-05-14T00:00:01'))
  ]

interface PersonWithAge extends Person {
  readonly age: number;
}

export function toPersonWithAge(person: Person): PersonWithAge  {
    const birthDate = person.dob;
    const age = differenceInYears(birthDate, new Date() )
    return {
      ...person,
      age
    }
}
```

**person.component.ts**

```
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor() { }
   persons=persons;

   ngOnInit(): void {
       }
 }
```

Assuming the approach so far is correct, then how and where (filename) would I do the next stage of this to convert the array of persons to an array of PersonWithAge so that I can use it in my html template with *ngFor.

I am new to Typescript so a verbose answer would be best.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Person {
    constructor(
    public name: string,
    public dob: Date,
    ) { }
    
    // getter to calculate age from dob
    get age(): number{
        //calculate month difference from current date in time  
        var month_diff = Date.now() - this.dob.getTime(); 
        //convert the calculated difference in date format  
        var age_dt = new Date(month_diff);   
        //extract year from date      
        var year = age_dt.getUTCFullYear();  
        //now calculate the age of the user  
        var age = Math.abs(year - 1970);  
        return age; 
    }
}

let persons:Person[]=[];

persons = [
    new Person("John", new Date('1976-01-26T00:00:00')),
    new Person("Julia", new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')),
    new Person("John", new Date('1967-07-05T00:00:01')),
    new Person("Ryan", new Date('2010-05-14T00:00:01'))
]

persons.forEach(x => console.log(x.age));
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesnt provide an array or PersonsWithAge that I can use in my componenet?

Comment: question updated - I am dealing with an array of persons.

Comment: Yes. The array of persons, needs to become an array of PersonsWithAge.

Comment: Yes thats one way. I was looking to see how to do it with a remap through a interface.

Comment: Maybe something like this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61jgzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-with-age%2Fperson-with-age.component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wgfgov?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pipe to transform your list of Person into a list of PersonWithAge (read [here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) for more information about Pipe and how to create a Pipe)

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'pipePersonWithAge'
})
export class PipePersonWithAgePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(persons: Person[]): PersonWithAge[] {
    return persons.map(person => this.toPersonWithAge(person));
  }
  toPersonWithAge(person: Person): PersonWithAge  {
    const birthDate = person.dob;
    const age = differenceInYears(birthDate, new Date() )
    return {
      ...person,
      age
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your template file (.html file, I'll call it `demo-page.html`), you will use the pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of (persons | pipePersonWithAge)">Name {{person.name}} - Age: {{person.age}}</div>
```

Note that the .html file is linked to a .ts file (I'll call it `demo-page.ts`), which contains your fake data "persons":

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-page',
  templateUrl: './demo-page.html'
})
export class DemoPage {
  persons: Person[] = [
    new Person("John", new Date('1976-01-26T00:00:00')),
    new Person("Julia", new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')),
    new Person("John", new Date('1967-07-05T00:00:01')),
    new Person("Ryan", new Date('2010-05-14T00:00:01'))
  ];
}
```

P/S: As you may ask "Why do I need to use a Pipe and not just use a normal function?". The answer is: Pipe helps avoid re-calculation each time Angular's change-detection runs (which maybe very frequently). The Pipe will re-calculate only if its param's value changes (because Pipe is "pure" by default), therefore Pipes are very good performant. For example, the Pipe above only recalculate if one of the persons change its name or date-of-birth.

Comment: Looks like a very clean approach. Will try it in a fiddle.

Comment: I have my Person class definition ,and fake data in person.model.ts - not in the component,. Is there a way to pass the array containing the fake Person data to the PipePersonWtihAgeClass?

Comment: Nearly there https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-37xkko?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-with-age%2Fperson-with-age.component.ts - what does that error mean?

Comment: @AlGrant Sorry but I don't see any error in your stackblitz. Did you mean the error is age being negative? I think you should change `const age = differenceInYears(birthDate, new Date() )` into `const age = differenceInYears(new Date(), birthDate )`

Answer (score 0):

**person.model.ts**

```
import { differenceInYears, parse } from "date-fns"

enum sex {Female="Female", Male="Male"}

export class Person {
  constructor(
    public firstname: string,
    public middlename: string,
    public lastname: string,
    public sex: sex,
    public dob: Date,
  ) { }
}

export let persons:Person[]=[];
  persons = [
    new Person("John", "Barry", "Eastwood", sex.Male, new Date('1976-01-26T00:00:00')),
    new Person("Julia", "Marie", "Roberts", sex.Female, new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00')),
    new Person("John", "Travis", "Travolta", sex.Female, new Date('1967-07-05T00:00:01')),
    new Person("Ryan", "William", "Davis", sex.Male, new Date('2010-05-14T00:00:01'))
  ]

export interface PersonWithAge extends Person {
  readonly age: number;
}

export function toPersonWithAge(person: Person): PersonWithAge  {
    const birthDate = person.dob;
    const age = differenceInYears( new Date(), birthDate )
    return {
      ...person,
      age
    }
}
```

**person-with-age.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { persons, toPersonWithAge, PersonWithAge } from '../models/person.model';
import { of, map, Observable } from 'rxjs';


interface MyComponentView {
  readonly persons: ReadonlyArray<PersonWithAge>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person-with-age',
  templateUrl: './person-with-age.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person-with-age.component.css']
})
export class PersonWithAgeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  readonly persons$ = of(persons);

  readonly vm$: Observable<MyComponentView> = this.persons$.pipe(
  map(persons => persons.map(toPersonWithAge)),
  map(persons => ({ persons }))
  )

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Then in the view:

**person-with-age.component.html**

```
<ul *ngIf="vm$ | async as vm">
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col">Firstname</th>
  <th scope="col">Lastname</th>
  <th scope="col">DOB</th>
  <th scope="col">Age</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr *ngFor="let person of vm.persons"><td>{{ person.firstname }}</td><td>{{ person.lastname }}</td><td>{{ person.dob | date }}</td><td>{{ person.age }}</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Working fiddle here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-61jgzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-with-age%2Fperson-with-age.component.html

Answer (score 0):

try using [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

public getAge(birthdate: any): number {
// moment(new Date()).diff('1976-01-26T00:00:00', 'years') => 46
  return moment(new Date()).diff(birthdate, 'years');
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).